# Newbie cannot program Hello world app

Tags: android, eclipse

I recently downloaded Eclipse (Galileo), the Android SDK and Java.  I followed instructions to write the "Hello World" app http://developer.android.com/guide/tutorials/hello-world.html from the developers'webpage and ran the app.  a window opens with a phone screen that reads "ANDROID" on the left and a keyboard image on the right. It does not resemble the image on the webpage, wherein the result should read Hello Android.

Last p.m. I tried several times to run 2 messages appeared in the Console of the Eclipse SDK program:

> Hello Android]ActivityManager: Can't dispatch DDM chunk 46454154: no
>   handler defined
>
> Hello Android]ActivityManager: Error: Unable to connect to activity
>   manager; is the system running?

How do I correct?  Thank you.

Comment: Jeff, did you download ADT (Android Development Tools)?

Comment: I restarted app.2 error messages.The first:
Description Project 'HelloAndroid' is missing required source folder:'gen'
Resource  HelloAndroid
Path
Location  Build path
Type Build  Path Problem
The other error message:
Project cannot be built until build path errors are resolved
Package Explorer: I do see a folder named gen. R click on properties, location is HelloAndroid\gen
I R clicked on the error, Quick Fix, Quick Fix window appears
Select a fix:  Configure build path...
 Clicked "Finish"
next window: Properties for HelloAndroid
Clicked "Finish"
next window: Properties for HelloAndroid

Comment: On left Java Build Path is highlighted.
Now what?  Thanks

Comment: Oh boy, I could still see the old HelloAndroid app in the Package explorer window. R clicking that, I chose "delete"
Single error msg: Project cannot be built until build path errors are resolved.
Closed program, reopened. 2nd error msg: can't run program until SDK loads.
closed program reopened. same 2 errors. then suddenly errors disappeared. My computer may be just too slow, I hope, or it has some randomizing error.I have a Dell Dimwitmension. Pentium 4 at 2.66GHz 4Gb of RAM.
Must be more patient.

Comment: It works. Thank you for your help. Mea culpa.
Please accept my apologies for taking your valuable time

Answer (score 2):

The "Android" on the left is just the emulator starting up. You see, it's actually a full-on emulated environment running inside a virtual machine so it takes a little time to start. If you let it finish booting up you should be able to run your program in it.

Comment: On my reasonably fast system it takes about 1 minute for the emulator to start.

Comment: Thanks, I'll get up & leave for a few minutes next time

Comment: once it's started, don't close the emulator. you only need to start it once, and also if something goes horribly wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Having *just* entered the world of Android/Eclipse/Java (on MAC-OSX 10.6) etc., I went down exactly the same path and had EXACTLY the same experience. Here's a few "First Timer" tips I'd like to offer you...

A. Things take time...  to refresh your components, to launch the emulator, to load a new/old project, etc. I am running on a screaming MACBook Pro and --- Things Take Time.

B. "Eclipse" is NOT Visual Studio. e.g. To open a demo project you'd think "PROJECT - > OPEN..."  bzzzzt. Wrong answer.. you "IMPORT..." into your current WORKSPACE. The workspace seems like the VS "Solution" space ... but early impressions tells me its probably A LOT more than that.

C. The DEFAULT PORT Number for attaching DDMS (the debugger) to your emulator is WRONG. My Version of Eclipse-Galileo (downloaded just yesterday) has the TCP port for connecting to the emulator set as default to 8600.... I could NOT get the d@rn thing to attach. I had read (somewhere --> starting a brand new development adventure like this *always* means a ton of reading up front) that the emulator *really* wants to talk on port 8200. I went into the PROPERTIES of DDMS and made the change and viola'

And finally,

D. Pay attention to the little "progress bar" in the lower right-hand corner of the IDE. I am amazed at how many times it wakes up by me pressing some "refresh" or other button... see A.

regards,
tob

Comment: turning off build automatically can help if you don't want to see that progress bar going 24/7.

Comment: I just got an ANDROID gray legend over a black screen, I changed the port of the DDMS to 8200 and then my app finally worked, thanks, you are very voted up!

Comment: Thanks, and BTW, I recently starting using NetBeans for android development and like it alot. Its MUCH faster at just about everything. The drawback is a significantly less developed GUI BUILDER (as in no drag and drop at all - just XML.) But I can develop the GUI and the widget's properties in Eclipse then copy the XML into the Netbeans project!